# Sudden strange spike in app downloads from china on iTunesConnect?

Tags: iphone, download, app-store-connect

Several years ago I released an app (a free game) for iOS, which was largely unsucessful, settling to around an average of 5 downloads a month (terrible, I know). However, I recently happend to notice a huge (relatively) spike in downloads, up to around 300 downloads over the last 10 days.

Something seems strange about this latest batch of downloads however, for one thing they are all from China (My app is only localized for English, and never marketed outside the U.S.), and the "Active devices (opt-in only)" statistic shows 3 devices used over that same time period.

Even stranger, the "Product Page Views" statistic shows only 6 views over this same period that had 300 downloads?!

Is something nefarious going on, or might there be a benign explanation for this huge spike in downloads?

If anyone is curious, or if it helps find the cause, the app is Acorn Mayhem, [as found here](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/acorn-mayhem/id894369624?mt=8). (Note: this is not intended as self promotion, and if including the link violates stack overflow rules, feel free to edit it out)

in response to being put on hold:
This question appears to have been put on hold as "off topic", I don't belive it should be, it does involve tools used directly and exclusively for programming (iTunes connect, which is only used by programmers) It would not be seen by the people who actually use it if it was on superuser, and I think the number of other people who have experienced the same problem and replied in a short time shows that it is on topic and helpful to a large portion of the programming community.

There is a thread on Apple forums about the issue https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/84146

Comment: I have seen spikes from china and other asian countries from random app aggregators putting it on some random "review" page. sometimes 30, sometimes 1000. I stopped trying to track them down =/

Comment: @solenoid good to know. Any idea why that would/could result in the product page views still staying low as the downloads spiked?

Comment: No idea - it never seems to match up or make sense

Comment: A number of people have seen this; https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/84146. I had the same issue with my free apps. One Christmas novelty app that typically gets a few downloads *at christmas* started getting hundreds of daily downloads from China. I am not sure what is happening but I have just withdrawn my apps from China.

Comment: I just had the same thing happen to me. I would get 10-20 downloads a week. Now I got 300+ all from China in last week. Checked out sessions and new users to see an internal spike. Nothing. Weird.

Comment: I see this too since August 17

Comment: Same here too.  Both of my apps, that were getting a small handful of downloads a month, have both been downloaded 700+ times each, starting on about 16/08.  This was not reflected in advertising earnings so I though something was up.  My biggest concern was that Apple might see this as something underhand on my part, but the fact that so many other people are reporting it hopefully means they will investigate and get to the bottom of it.

Comment: This has been happening me too in the last 2 weeks. It’s strange. Did you hear anything from Apple about it?

Comment: @ScottB. I didn't contact Apple about it, although apparently KeithL did. As far as I know Apple has not replied yet. I hope this question gets enough reopen votes to allow actual answers again.

Comment: I've had the same issue with my free apps. I read on the Apple forum that one of the users disabled downloads from China, and then saw a 30% decrease in downloads from the US when he did that. I removed China from available countries about 4 days ago, and I can also say that doing so reduced the number of downloads from US, but for me, in the vicinity of 60%. There is definitely something weird going on.

Comment: I've been seeing this since the beginning of last month. 100% increases in downloads on apps that get very few views normally, with no increase in actual usage. All additional downloads are from China.

I also disagree that this question is off-topic, as it is most certainly not in regards to "general computing hardware and software".

Comment: Started with one of our apps on the 24th of August. Noticed a 1000% increase in downloads and turns out that China was suddenly responsible for 80% of the downloads. It's an app targeted at the Norwegian market so we should have zero downloads from there. The rest of our apps are unaffected so far.

Comment: I had the same issue with both of my apps starting in August but my downloads have gone back to normal since September 29. Can anyone confirm?

Comment: @Kian same here, china downloads dropped back to zero couple weeks ago.

Answer (score 15):

I reported this to Apple yesterday through iTunesConnect and received a call back today (my spike started 8/16 and is just starting to trail off now). They are investigating this; the call lasted over 10 minutes. They promised to keep me in the loop so I will report back when I hear something.

Comment: Good to know Apple is aware of this and looking into it, let us know what they say when they reply! Thanks!

Comment: IMO they're doing this to hide illegal paid-downloads activity. That's the only reasonable explanation I could find. Meaning, some website allow app developers to buy downloads to push their app, but if they would only mass download the paying app, Apple would find out. So they download tons of random apps in addition, so it wouldn't be so obvious.

Comment: @Kof that's what I suspected as well, but it's odd that it's affecting so many people, all at the same time.

Comment: @Kof that's an interesting theory... I will look into Chinese local news to see what's really happening. I am not worried at all. But I am really curious now... haha.

Comment: @Kof that's what I thought when I also see the Chinese numbers. What is also interesting that iTunesConnect app install numbers are not following the download numbers. If we are not geting Chinese monetization from the new downloads we could exclude our apps from the Chinese store thus we might help stopping the illegal appstore manipulation.

Comment: @KeithL Did you get any updates from Apple since then? Still seeing lots of downloads from China daily (started 17/08)

Comment: No reply yet. I have pinged them and will give an update one way or another by Friday 9/22.

Comment: Noone seems to understand whats going on. I am very curious.

Comment: No response as of yet. I will post if I hear anything.

Comment: After a ping, quickly got a request for more info - screenshots - which is odd, you would think they would have this data. Of note however, there is at least one unrelated bug in the graphs. Stay tuned...

Comment: Sigh. In the last few days I received two contradictory messages. The first stated that the team I was talking to, let's call them Support, had filed a bug with engineering and received the message "We appreciate you reporting this concern. Sales and Trends reporting is working correctly."

Comment: The other message, which came after this one, stated that engineering is investigating any and all such reports but due to Apple's privacy policy they will not be providing more information to me unless it directly relates to revising my specific download numbers for my app.

Comment: Meanwhile, as of 9/30, I am getting only 1 or 2 downloads per day from China (peak of hundreds, monotonically decreasing). So perhaps 'engineering' has in fact found the problem. 

I am sorry that I have no more to report.

Comment: I know this is old, but any news on this? I'm experiencing similar behavior.

Answer (score 6):

same here too.  a game I released a year ago had very few downloads.  Over the last two months I have seen a slight increase in downloads, 1 or 2, maybe up to 5 per day, all from China.  All of a sudden in the last week I have seen 50, 80, and yesterday it peaked at 123 downloads.

I should also mention, this is a free game, with AdMob adverts.

Either the people who download the game aren't actually playing it at all (not one single ad show in China) or AdMob just doesn't work in China ???

either way - I've had about 500 downloads in the last week compared to ~300 in the entire previous year.

there is an IAP to upgrade the game and remove ads, needless to say, not one single user has paid.

a very strange situation.  I wish I knew what was driving the Chinese downloads but I can't find anything pointing to my game ?!  Also iTunes Connect seems to say they are coming from store browsing ?!

curiouser and curiouser ...

Comment: sorry. someone is bound to moan, this is not an answer.. the comment field was too restrictive...

Answer (score 5):

Similar story here:
I have 2 apps, that I made about 2 years ago basically for fun. They get about 20-35 downloads per day. Since 17 Aug, they receive about 120-150 per day, all the extra downloads from China. These numbers don't have any effect on my admob performance, and no significant changes on firebase. I call them ghost-downloads.
I switched one of the apps from free to paid. The downloads for that app went down to zero (as I expected)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to have an accurate real user traffic stats, check the "Daily Active Users" & "Daily Active Devices" from itunes connect as reference.

From my own stats, I can see there are extra ~100 download spike daily from Chinese market, but the DAU stays the same, which means these downloads were not initiated by users, might be a 3rd party app crawler automated the crawling for apps using simulators or automation iOS devices. So don't worry about it, the trend should go away in a while.

If you are curious which 3rd party app crawlers are downloading your apps, google "[your app name] + 应用", you should find tons of them. Websites like these crawl lots of app data and run SEO to attract traffic, and benefits from online advertisements (adsense, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

I have the same phenomenon across free apps in the App store.  It results in approximately 1000 downloads from China per day, spread pretty evenly across about 15 apps. Each app download is around 100-200MB so that implies a reasonable burden on the App store servers if it is happening with other apps also.  I contacted Apple and they did not seem to ask anything but questions that clearly indicated a complete lack of interest in understanding the issue.  They suggested that the problem was not a problem but a volume download program.  They then asked to see screenshots from affected users.

Comment: I eventually blocked downloads from China.  After leaving it for a few weeks I have again allowed downloads from China for one of the apps and the problems have not started up again.

Answer (score 2):

The exact same thing happened to me (hundreds of extra downloads per day from China only) within the past week. It's not just one app but every one I have created so far. At first I thought it was an iTunes Connect bug but maybe my apps were just featured somewhere public? There are over a Billion people there after all. ;)

Answer (score 2):

I would like to confirm this, and share some data as well. Take a look. The deviation in traffic started around mid of July, and all of my apps have been downloaded roughly in the same amount. Few days ago I noticed that downloads returned to their normal level. All of abnormal purchases took place from China. Maybe this will shed some light on the source, but I doubt that this traffic generated by real people.

[image: All apps have relatively same spike in numbers]

[image: Almost everything is from China, spike ended with the beginning of Oct 2017]

Comment: I can confirm, the download spike seems to have subsided (at least mostly, 7 day report shows 22 downloads, still much more than normal, but may be reflecting a day or two before the spike ended). I agree, it was definitely not caused by real people (at least in any normal, non-scammy situations). I wonder if Apple will ever reveal the cause of this strange behavior/data?

Answer (score 1):

At first I thought this was great news, a lot of downloads, but then my cynical side popped in. Perhaps they are downloading the IPAs unzipping them and looking at the source code. They would only have the front end, but that's half the solution. Here is an article about pirated apps

https://www.cultofmac.com/224075/china-has-its-own-app-store-that-lets-users-install-pirated-ios-apps-without-jailbreaking/

You want to look for ways to obfuscate your code.

Comment: Nah, at this large scale, it is highly unlikely they are trying to decompile your code and trying to copycat.

Comment: i don't think thats the reason and to do that they need only one IPA and they are downloading 100+ of 1 app daily.

Comment: Mine's open source; if they want the code, just follow the link on my app store page.

Answer (score 1):

Updates:

1. By the end of September my abnormal Chinese ghost-downloads have disappeared. Everything is back to normal.
2. On the 8th of September I experienced something much more extreme an unexpected: Approximately 6000 "downloads" from Sweden. It happened only once.

[image: Sudden spike from Sweden]